# Splitting a line into a list (with some difficulty)

Tags: python, list, function, split

I've been trying to work on an assignment and after hours of searching asking class mates and looking on here I can't work this out.

I have a text file containing +100000 lines of data in the format:

```
"Words" \t "float" \t "float"
```

and I'm trying to write a function which lets me search a line and pull out one piece of information. It works fine when I write it normally, but I cannot seem to put it into a function

```
FileList = Mammal.readlines()
Name,Latitude,Longitude = FileList[int].split("\t")
print (Name)

def LineToList(int):
    FileList = Text.readlines()
    A,B,C = FileList[int].split("\t")

LineToList(0)
print (A)
```

I receive this error.

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I've tried swapping out int for a letter, a ratio and adding lines to return values for A, B and C then printing them out but each time it fails.

Comment: How does the `A` in `print (A)` get its value?

Comment: Variables aren't all globals. If you define a variable inside one scope, it isn't automatically available in every scope.

Comment: A couple of problems: 1) using `int` as a variable is a bad idea since `int` is a built-in. 2) you seem to be trying to read the same file  again and again without closing it. Just read the lines into a list once.

Answer (score 2):

Your code reads the entire contents of an open file with `readlines()`, then processes only one line. If your function looks exactly as you show, it will succeed the first time you use it (as long as it's used on a freshly opened file); but on the second call there will be nothing more for `readlines()` to read, and you'll get back an empty list.

Here's a simpler way to convert an entire file:

```
lines = mammal.readlines()
values = [ row.split("\t") for row in lines ]
```

You then have all your values in one list of triples.

Also, note the capitalization. Python style uses names that start with a capital for user-defined types, not for ordinary variables.

Comment: And even shorter as `[ row.split("\t") for row in mammal ]`

Comment: @DYZ yes, but I'm keeping it transparent. If it were me I'd be using `csv.reader(..., delimiter="\t")`